# Format Kotlin with minimal indent for code blocks in constructor parameters, like Foo({ bar })

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, code-formatting, kotest

When formatting this code block (from the [Kotest documentation](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/testing-styles.html#free-spec)), Jetbrains Intellij or Android Studio adds a lot of unnecessary white space.

Original code:

```
class MyTests : FreeSpec({
     "String.length" - {
         "should return the length of the string" {
             "sammy".length shouldBe 5
             "".length shouldBe 0
         }
     }
})
```

After formating with ctrl+alt+L, this becomes

```
class MyTests : FreeSpec({
                             "String.length" - {
                                 "should return the length of the string" {
                                     "sammy".length shouldBe 5
                                     "".length shouldBe 0
                                 }
                             }
                         })
```

Is there a formatting setting to adjust this behavior?

I strongly suspect that there is a working combination of settings in Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin, but after trying out various combinations I could not figure it out.

Comment: Do you know that behavior of code formatting is configurable in the settings? -> Editor -> Code Style

Comment: Certainly, but I could not find a setting for this specific problem. But I strongly suspect there is a setting to adjust this, which is why I am asking this question.

Comment: I suspect there isn't a setting for this one because it's a rare case--lambda in a super-constructor call. Maybe it will look better if you start the lambda on the second line, and move the closing parenthesis to the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may duplicate a formating scheme to alter safely or just do the following things.

`Editor > Code Style > Kotlin > Wrapping and Braces > Function call arguments`

Uncheck `Align when multiline`

I also use Kotest FreeSpec. This was the tweak I made to have nice formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to format your snippet in `Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Canary 6` and it remains intact:
[image]

I suggest you to try a fresh installation of Android Studio/IntelliJ together with a fresh app using Kotest and see if the issue resurfaces.

If it doesn't then you can compare the following files of the two projects to figure out the difference:
`$projectRootDir/.idea/codeStyles/Project.xml`